# How to loop click with selenium and scrape each table with bs4?

Tags: python, loops, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some hidden tables (15 tables per page) which are expanded after clicking an arrow. (I'm attaching pictures: [Unexpanded tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUe9J.png) [Expanded tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAJLl.png) )

I'm attaching the HTML, too (sorry, it's a bit long)

```
<table class="footable table toggle-arrow-tiny default breakpoint footable-loaded" transparenturl="Images/arrow_none.gif" ascendingurl="Images/arrow_up.gif" customsortdirection="Ascending" custompageindex="0" customsortfield="fullname" custompagealphaindex="A" custompagemode="ABC" custompagealpharelative="A" descendingurl="Images/arrow_down.gif" customvirtualcount="1605" id="MainContent_gw_partners" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-toggle="true" scope="col" class="footable-visible footable-first-column"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-ignore="true" data-hide="phone, tablet" scope="col" class="footable-visible"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-ignore="true" data-hide="phone, tablet" scope="col" class="footable-visible">Titolo&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th scope="col" class="footable-visible">Cognome&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-ignore="true" data-hide="phone, tablet" scope="col" class="footable-visible">NPA&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-ignore="true" data-hide="phone" scope="col" class="footable-visible">Luogo&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-ignore="true" data-hide="phone" scope="col" class="footable-visible footable-last-column">Cantone&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s)&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Società&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Cognome&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">C/O&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Via&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">NPA&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Luogo&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Tel / Cellulare&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Cellulare  &nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Fax&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">e-mail&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Sito WEB&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Altri luoghi di lavoro&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th data-hide="all" scope="col" style="display: none;">Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s)&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
        <tr class="row_white footable-detail-show">
            <td class="footable-visible footable-first-column"><span class="footable-toggle"></span>&nbsp;</td><td class="footable-visible">

                    </td><td class="footable-visible">&nbsp;</td><td class="footable-visible">

                        ABBONDANZIERI Katia
                    </td><td class="footable-visible">
                        1204
                        <br>

                    </td><td class="footable-visible">
                        Genève
                        <br>

                    </td><td class="footable-visible footable-last-column">
                        GE
                        <br>

                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        197.&nbsp;Omeopatia, 202.&nbsp;Linfodrenaggio&nbsp;manuale, 205.&nbsp;Massaggio&nbsp;classico, 664.&nbsp;Riflessoterapia&nbsp;generale
                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        ABBONDANZIERI Katia
                    </td><td style="display: none;">


                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        Place du Cirque, 2
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        1204
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        Genève
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        022 328 23 44 
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        079 601 92 75 
                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thZone"><div class="zCat">METHODES DE MASSAGE</div><div class="zThr">Linfodrenaggio manuale</div><div class="zThr">Massaggio classico</div><div class="zCat">METHODES PRESCRIPTIVES</div><div class="zThr">Omeopatia</div><div class="zCat">METHODES REFLEXES</div><div class="zThr">Riflessoterapia generale</div></div>
                    </td>
        </tr><tr class="footable-row-detail" style="display: table-row;"><td class="footable-row-detail-cell" colspan="7"><div class="footable-row-detail-inner"><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s):</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">197.&nbsp;Omeopatia, 202.&nbsp;Linfodrenaggio&nbsp;manuale, 205.&nbsp;Massaggio&nbsp;classico, 664.&nbsp;Riflessoterapia&nbsp;generale</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Cognome:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">ABBONDANZIERI Katia</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Via:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Place du Cirque, 2</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">NPA:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">1204</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Luogo:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Genève</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Tel / Cellulare:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">022 328 23 44</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Cellulare:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">079 601 92 75</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s):</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value"><div class="thZone"><div class="zCat">METHODES DE MASSAGE</div><div class="zThr">Linfodrenaggio manuale</div><div class="zThr">Massaggio classico</div><div class="zCat">METHODES PRESCRIPTIVES</div><div class="zThr">Omeopatia</div><div class="zCat">METHODES REFLEXES</div><div class="zThr">Riflessoterapia generale</div></div></div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="row_grey footable-detail-show">
            <td class="footable-visible footable-first-column"><span class="footable-toggle"></span>&nbsp;</td><td class="footable-visible">

                            <a href="http://www.kinesiopourtous.ch" target="_blank">
                                <img title="Link internet" alt="" style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 7px" src="Images/pictoSiteInternet.jpg" width="12" height="12" border="0">
                            </a>

                    </td><td class="footable-visible">&nbsp;</td><td class="footable-visible">
                        <img id="MainContent_gw_partners_img1_1" src="Images/multi.gif">
                        ABEGG Sophie
                    </td><td class="footable-visible">
                        1212
                        <br>
                        1875<br>
                    </td><td class="footable-visible">
                        Grand-Lancy
                        <br>
                        <nobr>Morgins</nobr><nobr><br>
                    </nobr></td><td class="footable-visible footable-last-column">
                        GE
                        <br>
                        VS<br>
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        199.&nbsp;Kinesiologia
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        Kinéso pour tous
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        ABEGG Sophie
                    </td><td style="display: none;">


                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        Rue du Bachet 8
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        1212
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        Grand-Lancy
                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        076 365 63 86
                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                            <a href="mailto:sophie@kinesiopourtous.ch">sophie[at]kinesiopourtous.ch
                            </a>

                    </td><td style="display: none;">

                            <a href="http://www.kinesiopourtous.ch" target="_blank">
                                www.kinesiopourtous.ch
                            </a>

                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        Résidence Bellevue, Rte de France 22, 1875 Morgins, CH<br>
                    </td><td style="display: none;">
                        <div class="thZone"><div class="zCat">METHODES ENERGETIQUES MANUELLES</div><div class="zThr">Kinesiologia</div></div>
                    </td>
        </tr><tr class="footable-row-detail"><td class="footable-row-detail-cell" colspan="7"><div class="footable-row-detail-inner"><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s):</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">199.&nbsp;Kinesiologia</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Società:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Kinéso pour tous</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Cognome:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">ABEGG Sophie</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Via:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Rue du Bachet 8</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">NPA:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">1212</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Luogo:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Grand-Lancy</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Cellulare:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">076 365 63 86</div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">e-mail:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value"><a href="mailto:sophie@kinesiopourtous.ch">sophie[at]kinesiopourtous.ch
                            </a></div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Sito WEB:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value"><a href="http://www.kinesiopourtous.ch" target="_blank">
                                www.kinesiopourtous.ch
                            </a></div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Altri luoghi di lavoro:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value">Résidence Bellevue, Rte de France 22, 1875 Morgins, CH<br></div></div><div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s):</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value"><div class="thZone"><div class="zCat">METHODES ENERGETIQUES MANUELLES</div><div class="zThr">Kinesiologia</div></div></div></div></div></td></tr><tr class="row_white">
            <td class="footable-visible footable-first-column"><span class="footable-toggle"></span>&nbsp;</td><td class="footable-visible">
```

So I'm using Selenium to click and BeautifulSoup 4 to scrape tables.

I would like to create a loop to click each arrow (15 arrows in each page) and scrape the data from each table (13 rows in each table. If data is missing the cell should blank in the outputed excel file).

Any help, please?

Comment: probably better if you could provide the url too

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it

Comment: sorry, I should have been more specific. I meant the url/code you used to get to the html you in your sample above

Comment: Oh... I used the Inspect tool in firefox to find the code for the beginning of the table. Then I viewed the page's source code, located the beginning of the table (by searching the code I found with inspect) and copy-paste.

Comment: ah ok. what did you have in the search fields then. The link only takes me to the initial page.

Comment: Here's what I did: in the drop-down menu "Cantone" I clicked on GE. Clicked on the checkbox "Confermo di effettuare una ricerca a fine privato" and then the button "Ricerca". Then I expanded the tables for the first two names and then got the source. I hope I've been clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect, you can see it's Request Method: POST so used a different method.

If you'd prefer to still use selenium, just let me know and I can try to work that way out too.

You're going to need to go grab the Form Data, and copy that into the payload dictionary. I did not include the whole thing, because it's just too long, but I included a snipit of it in the code so you could see the format.

[image]

Then I just used pandas to grab the table with the data.

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it'
headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '55755',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1140629371.1547917375; _gid=GA1.2.1588639047.1547917375; ASP.NET_SessionId=fmxjh5jxwuq10awmqch1ztjz; __AntiXsrfToken=1d9c575ab1494ab29d2e796e2853eaac; _gat=1',
'Host': 'www.asca.ch',
'Origin': 'http://www.asca.ch',
'Referer': 'http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}


payload = {
'ctl00$RadScriptManagerMaster': 'ctl00$RadScriptManagerMaster|ctl00$MainContent$btn_submit',
'RadStyleSheetManager1_TSSM': ';|636398747139118389:c7e0c438;|636304438089400012:39e38b4c;|636304438089880540:19119943;|636304438090200892:b81c9af7;|636304438090180870:bb009068;|636304438089390001:e78ed9b3;|636325253237635520:dedafabf;|636304438089530155:5961cfc1;|636304438090290991:d08fa23c;|636304438089530155:7fafd27a',
'RadScriptManagerMaster_TSM': ';;System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en-US:af7dd01d-1544-48f6-a85d-1285ae370050:ea597d4b:b25378d2;||:460a097d:7a38c288:ace9a216;Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.1.403.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4:en-US:ca584452-327f-4858-bf00-fb22c6f6fd75:16e4e7cd:ed16cbdc:f7645509:24ee1bba:f46195d3:2003d0b8:88144a7a:1e771326:aa288e2d:258f1c72:7165f74;',
'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_partners':'' ,
'ctl00_MainContent_ddl_partners_ClientState':'' ,
'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_countries': 'Suisse',
'ctl00_MainContent_ddl_countries_ClientState': '',
'ctl00$MainContent$ddl_cantons': 'GE',

...
...

'__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
'RadAJAXControlID': 'ctl00_MainContent_RadAjaxManager1'
}


r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = r.text

tables = pd.read_html(r.text)
data = tables[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (data)
    Unnamed: 0                        ...                                           Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s).1
0          NaN                        ...                          METHODES DE MASSAGELinfodrenaggio manualeMassa...
1          NaN                        ...                                METHODES ENERGETIQUES MANUELLESKinesiologia
2          NaN                        ...                                      METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio classico
3          NaN                        ...                          METHODES AYURVEDIQUESHatha YogaMETHODES PSYCHO...
4          NaN                        ...                          METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio classicoMETHODES ...
5          NaN                        ...                                            METHODES PRESCRIPTIVESOmeopatia
6          NaN                        ...                          METHODES ENERGETIQUES MANUELLESReikiMETHODES O...
7          NaN                        ...                          METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio tradizionale thai...
8          NaN                        ...                          METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio classicoMassaggio...
9          NaN                        ...                                      METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio empirico
10         NaN                        ...                          METHODES PSYCHOLOGIQUES COMPLEMENTAIRESConsigl...
11         NaN                        ...                          METHODES PRESCRIPTIVESConsigli dietetici (MCO)...
12         NaN                        ...                          METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio classicoMassaggio...
13         NaN                        ...                                   METHODES DE MASSAGEMassaggio terapeutico
14         NaN                        ...                          METHODES DE MASSAGELinfodrenaggio manualeMETHO...

[15 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I was thinking of creating two loops though (one inside the other): the first loop is click an arrow and get the data (this loop gets the data for all the tables of one page) and the next loop goes from one page to another. I don't know how to create those loops tho.

Comment: I'm working on that now. hopefully have something back to you in about 5-10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Selenium way to expand those tables. There is a better way to handle the tie it takes to load, but just wanted to get this to you asap, so just went with a `time.sleep`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


url = 'http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Click the dropdown, select GE, click Confermo, click Ricerca
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_Arrow"]').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[9]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent__chkDisclaimer"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_btn_submit"]').click()
time.sleep(5)

#Function to Expand Tables
def expand_tables():
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_gw_partners"]/tbody/tr')
    for row in rows:
        row.click()

# Function to Click Next Page        
def click_next_page():
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_btnNextPackId"]').click()



page = 1
num_of_pages = True
while num_of_pages == True:
    print ('Page: %s' %page)
    expand_tables()

    ## Your code to Parse the Tables ## 

    try:
        click_next_page()
        page += 1
    except:
        print ('You are at the end')


    time.sleep(2)






# When finished
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you @chitown88  I'll try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: don't use time.sleep()

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, I'm switching that out right now, but do you know why it shouldn't be used with selenium? I've seen people suggest that more than once, but never really say why to not use it.

Comment: use `for _ in range(num_of_pages)` instead of that while loop

Comment: @chitown88 Using a fixed sleep, you will either needlessly wait until it expires (making execution slower), or it won't be a sufficient amount of time for erverything to load.  To get around this, Selenium includes functionality to poll the DOM and wait only as long as necessary.  see WebDriverWait (aka explicit wait)

Comment: Oh ok. That's exactly my assumption. I thought maybe there was some other reason. I am aware of the explicit wait.

Comment: Well, I have some questions about the code: 1. Shouldn't the first loop [def expand_tables():] be inside the second one [def click_next_page():] ? 2. I don't know how much pages are there, but of course there are much morethan 10 (num_of_pages = 10) 3. When does the tables expanding stop? There are 15 tables/page, but the loop doesn't seem to show that. Sorry for my noob questions. I'm new to programming and this forum.

Comment: no worries. 1) Those are separate functions. The loop starts right after num_of_pages, and once you search, you're on page 1, so you'd want to expand the tables, beofre going to the next page. 2) Yes there are more than 10 pages, I just selected that to see if it'll run. It does. You can manually check for the number of pages, or write a little more code that can look up how many pages there are 3) the table expanding stops when it runs out of rows. I didn't know if every page will have 15 to expand, so I didn't hard code that. But it will expand every table on the page

Comment: 2) Or you can just have it keep running as long as there's a "next page" buttin

Comment: Can you please have a look at the code about parsing tables? I poste as an answer right after the first question. (Should I have opened another question for that?)

Comment: After executing the code it opens chromium and it goes until expanding all the tables on the first page (except the first table) and stops. [Here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s440/sh/04dbc87b-ab3a-4fac-b8a7-6fa9ea766d74/7823eee0d511137203d22cca71466447) is the terminal output.

Comment: I’ll look at it in a little bit.

Comment: not sure what the issue is. It runs through completely fine for me. The error seems to show that it isn't finding an element. When I get more time I'll look more in to it

Comment: Thank you @chitown88 I would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat but I have only 11 reputation. Can I send you the whole code I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't fit my code to the comments, so I'm posting as an answer.

This is my code for parsing tables:

```
# To find all the tables
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'footable'})

# To get all rows in that table
rows = table.find_all('tr')

# A function to process each row
def processRow(row):
    #All rows with hidden data
    dataFields = row.find_all('td', {'style': True}
    output = {}
    #Fixed index numbers are not ideal but in this case will work
    output['Discipline'] = dataFields[0].text
    output['Cogome'] = dataFields[2].text
    output['Cellulare'] = dataFields[8].text
    output['email'] = dataFields[10].text
    return output

# Declaring a list to store all results
results = []

# Iterating over all the rows and storing the processed result in a list
for row in rows:
    results.append(processRow(row))

print(results)


    click_next_page()
    time.sleep(3)
    count += 1
```

I think something is not ok. I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at "output = {}" below # A function to process each row.

Comment: you're missing  `)`   should be `dataFields = row.find_all('td', {'style': True})`

Comment: OH, thank you. Missed that. By the way, how did you install selenium on your machine? I did it by pip install selenium. I'm using python 3.6.7 on ubuntu. I'm getting complains about "from selenium import webdriver". The error is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'"

Comment: you also need to download webdriver too i think [link here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). And ya, I did pip install [link here for that info](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

Comment: Well, I tried ChromeDriver and geckoDriver (I changed the code to drive.Firefox). I tried the directions [here](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu) too, but to no avail.

Comment: Well, I figured it out: selenium was installed for python 2 (with pip install selenium), so I uninstalled it and installed for python 3 (pip3 install python)